# NPM packages not being installed using npx

Tags: node.js, npm, esbuild

I am currently working on a CLI application with NPM, but for some reason I get the following error after I package it and try running it:

```bash
> npx -y [organization]-[package]-0.0.1.tgz
node:internal/errors:496
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\wathhr\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\9765d4346a8e56c1\node_modules\[organization]\[package]\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\index.js' imported from C:\Users\wathhr\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\9765d4346a8e56c1\node_modules\[organization]\[package]\dist\bin.js
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:324:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:943:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1129:11)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:835:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:77:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

Relevant parts of the `package.json`:

```json
{
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "prepare": "npm run build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/fs-extra": "^11.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^20.5.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.4.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.4.0",
    "esbuild": "^0.19.2",
    "eslint": "^8.47.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@clack/prompts": "^0.7.0",
    "command-exists": "^1.2.9",
    "fs-extra": "^11.1.1",
    "ts-deepmerge": "^6.2.0"
  },
  "bin": "dist/bin.js",
  "main": "dist/bin.js",
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "templates"
  ]
}
```

I am using esbuild to bundle the app with the following config:

```js
{
  entryPoints: ['./src/index.ts'],
  outfile: './dist/bin.js',
  banner: {
    'js': '#!/usr/bin/env node',
  },
  minify: false,
  bundle: true,
  external: ['./node_modules/*'], // don't bundle node_modules because it causes errors
  platform: 'node',
  format: 'esm',
  logLevel: 'info',
}
```

How can I fix this?

<sub>if you need more information please ask so I can provide it :)</sub>

Comment: the node is trying to find `fs-extra`. Perhaps I'd like to test to change the external to `external: ['fs-extra']` to only exclude fs-extra from bundling.

Comment: `npm i package` installs a package named package. `npx` runs commands without installing the package or as said here: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npx: This command allows you to run an arbitrary command from an npm package (either one installed locally, or fetched remotely), in a similar context as running it via `npm run`.

Comment: @Gxogac I just realized esbuild was compiling the imports to something like `../node_modules/fs-extra/lib/index.js`! replacing `./node_modules/*` with the package names fixed the imports somehow? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing

```js
external: ['./node_modules/*']
```

in the esbuild config with

```js
external: [
  ...Object.keys(pkg.devDependencies ?? {}),
  ...Object.keys(pkg.dependencies ?? {}),
]
```

fixed the issue!